# Understanding Sets and Sequences using String checking as an example

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a string which I would like to cross check if it is purely made of letters and space.

```
 val str = "my long string to test"
 val purealpha = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toSet

 if (str.forall(purestring(_))) println("PURE") else "NOTPURE"
```

The above CONCISE code does the job. However, if I run it this way:

```
 val str = "my long string to test"
 val purealpha = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   // not converted toSet

 str.forall(purealpha(_))    // CONCISE code
```

I get an error (found: Char ... required: Boolean) and it can only work using the contains method this way:

```
str.forall(purealpha.contains(_))
```

My question is how can I use the CONCISE form without converting the string to a Set. Any suggestions on having my own String class with the right combination of methods to enable the nice code; or maybe some pure function(s) working on strings.

It's just a fun exercise I'm doing, so I can understand the intricate details of various methods on collections (including apply method) and how to write nice concise code and classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach is to use a regex pattern.

```
val str = "my long string to test"
val purealpha = "[ a-z]+"
str matches purealpha   // res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Nice, concise and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the source code we can see that both these implementations are doing different things, although giving the same result.
When you are converting it to a `Set` and using the `forAll`, you are ultimately calling the `apply` method for the set. Here is how the apply is called explicitly in your code, also using named parameters in the anonymous functions:

```
if (str.forall(s => purestring.apply(s))) println("PURE") else "NOTPURE" // first example
str.forall(s => purealpha.apply(s)) // second example
```

Anyway, let's take a look at the source code for apply for Set (gotten from GenSetLike.scala):

```
/** Tests if some element is contained in this set.
   *
   *  This method is equivalent to `contains`. It allows sets to be interpreted as predicates.
   *  @param elem the element to test for membership.
   *  @return  `true` if `elem` is contained in this set, `false` otherwise.
   */
  def apply(elem: A): Boolean = this contains elem
```

When you leave the `String` literal, you have to specifically call the `.contains` (this is the source code for that gotten from SeqLike.scala):

```
/** Tests whether this $coll contains a given value as an element.
   *  $mayNotTerminateInf
   *
   *  @param elem  the element to test.
   *  @return     `true` if this $coll has an element that is equal (as
   *              determined by `==`) to `elem`, `false` otherwise.
   */
  def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean = exists (_ == elem)
```

As you can imagine, doing an apply for the `String` literal will not give the same result as doing an apply for a Set.

A suggestion on having more conciseness is to omit the `(_)` entirely in the second example (compiler type inference will pick that up):

```
val str = "my long string to test"
val purealpha = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   // not converted toSet
str.forall(purealpha.contains)
```